# dynamic column reference in formula

Tags: excel, vba, reference, formula

I'd like to place a formula 3 cells to the left of the last column. Is there a way to do this? Perhaps through a column address?

```
lc = .Cells(3, Columns.count).End(xlToLeft).Column
.Cells(3, lc + 3).Formula = "=CountCcolor(E3:N" & lrPT & ", " & .Cells(0, lc + 2) & "3)"
```

Regards,

Comment: Does that not work? What error does it give? It looks like you're missing something in your CountCColor - it's getting range `E3:N#,#3` instead of something like `E3:N9` or something.  What's the column you want for the second part? What's that range supposed to be? (I can't figure why there's a `", "` in there).

Comment: The function CountCcolor typically would look like this `=CountCcolor(range, criteria)` or `=CountCcolor(E3:N200, O3)`. I get a application or object defined error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`lc + 3` is three columns to the right, not the left but that is almost assuredly a typo. This should square your formula construction away.

```
lc = .Cells(3, Columns.count).End(xlToLeft).Column
.Cells(3, lc + 3).Formula = "=CountCcolor(E3:N" & lrPT & ", " & .Cells(3, lc + 2).ADDRESS & ")"
```

VBA's [Range.Address property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff837625.aspx) can output cell references in various combinations of relative and absolute addressing. I've left this as the default (e.g. absolute) but I do not believe it actually matters in your formula (single formula in single cell).

btw, if there are values in column N, the `lc + 2` will be referencing P3, not O3.